# Make some work on the main thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm in an application that has a lot of thread. In one of those thread, I need to run some lines on the main thread.

This is because windows XP frees I/O resources when the creator thread ends( Overlapped I/O ). I need to make instantiation in a Singleton creation.

How could I do this?

Before an off-topic answer:

This is not GUI related, so do not propose something like `myControler.BeginInvoke` since I've no GUI element

Comment: You'll have to make your main thread interact with the other thread.  This can be done with synchronization primitives like `AutoResetEvent`.  But, that's *really* hard to get right.  I think using a work queue of some sort would be a much better design.

Comment: Err.. don't end the the creator thread?  Would that not be easier?

Comment: @MartinJames I don't own the thread that is calling me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did this:

1. I added a `BlockingCollection` with all IPs I need to create
2. When I "start" my singleton, I just add my IPs in that collection
3. And I start a new thread, with the Background property to True, that iterate on this collection

This thread will not consume many resource since he will just be blocked on the wait of the next iteration, and it stays alive for the duration of the application.

I added a condition to do this for windows XP and lower.

Answer (score 3):

You can't just run some code on main thread, because it is probably busy doing something else. 
You need some framework for this task, and Windows UI messaging is an example of such framework.

If your application is non-ui, then you can implement a static message queue, put your delegate there, and continuously check that queue from the main thread, pooling the delegates from it and executing them.

However, the better approach would be to re-evaluate your applications architecture. Maybe you can isolate the work with the IO object to one thread.

Comment: Dispatch.Run(): the Dispatcher processes the event queue in a loop. The loop is referred to as a frame. The initial loop is typically initiated by the application by calling Run.

The main execution frame will continue until the Dispatcher is shutdown, and you can call ExitAllFrames() to stop the message pump.

Comment: I've something like 20+ classes between the start class and my singleton, in 5-6 different class library. I just can't make something and pray that the guy that use the library that use the library that use my library make some instantiation .

Comment: @David: I don't have access to any GUI element, how should I access to any dispatcher?